# Switch user as well as environment variable in Unix Shell Script

Tags: unix

I'm currently working on a script that logs into another user account using

```
su username -c "comand1; comand2"
```

There's no `sudo` command in the shell.

However the environment variables do not change.

For example, the work directories are different with different users. So when the user is switched in the script, I expect that the `$HOME` variable should contain different work directories.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `-l` (or just `-`) option to make it a login shell. See the manual for [`su(1)`](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/su.1.html).

Comment: it sort of worked but not what i desired. I called another script within the first script and work directory is correct in the second script. But the environment variables still no change in the first script

Comment: You should really specify what OS and what shell.

Answer (score 0):

One hack-ish kind of way would be put all `env` variables of the second user in a file (like `.bashrc`) and source it first in the list of the commands:

```
su username -c "source file_name; comand1; comand2"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

First: If you user `"` to delimit the argument for `-c` then everything in this argument is expanded by the **calling** shell and not by the executed shell. You can use `'` instead of `"` to prevent this.

Second: By default `su` does not perform the same steps as during a real user login. Use the `-l` or `-` options. This may be required in your case or not - just try it.

Together:

```
> echo $HOME
/root
> su -c "echo $HOME" user -l
/root
> su -c 'echo $HOME' user -l
/home/user
> su -c 'echo $HOME' user
/home/user
```